# Handle Sorting event of programmatically created gridviews

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

i have a project in which i need to display many gridviews. the number of gridviews depend on the number of tables the directory has.

For example:

Directory A = 8 tables

Directory B = 7 tables

if the user clicks directory A, 8 gridviews should be created.
I am already done with creating this gridviews programmatically, my problem now is **how can i handle each programmatically created gridviews' sorting event.**

This is how i create my gridviews:

```
foreach (XMLClasses.table dirTab in dir.table.ToList())
{
    if (dirTab.id == child.tabid)
    {
        List<XMLClasses.column> columns = new List<XMLClasses.column>();
        columns = dirTab.column;
        string[] rows = new string[columns.Count];
        int x = 0;
        foreach (XMLClasses.column col in columns.ToList())
        {
            dtContent.Columns.Add(col.title);
            rows[x] = "b";
            x = x + 1;
        }
        dtContent.Rows.Add(rows);
        GridView grdTables = new GridView();
        grdTables.AllowSorting = true;
        grdTables.DataSource = dtContent;
        grdTables.DataBind();
        grdTables.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
        grdTables.Sorting+=new GridViewSortEventHandler(grdTables_Sorting);

        pnlDirectory.Controls.Add(grdTables);

        Literal lt = new Literal();
        lt.Text = "<br/>";
        pnlDirectory.Controls.Add(lt);

    }
}
```

im stock with this. i dont know what to do next..

Somebody have any idea??
Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post some code please

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to create gridviews programmatically and set a name for them, you're able to handle the sorting.

```
void SortButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) {

String expression = "";
SortDirection direction;

// Create the sort expression from the values selected 
// by the user from the DropDownList controls. Multiple
// columns can be sorted by creating a sort expression
// that contains a comma-separated list of field names.
expression = SortList1.SelectedValue + "," + SortList2.SelectedValue;

//  Determine the sort direction. The sort direction
// applies only to the second column sorted.
switch (DirectionList.SelectedValue)
{
  case "Ascending":
    direction = SortDirection.Ascending;
    break;
  case "Descending":
    direction = SortDirection.Descending;
    break;
  default:
    direction = SortDirection.Ascending;
    break;
}

// Use the Sort method to programmatically sort the GridView
// control using the sort expression and direction.
CustomersGridView.Sort(expression, direction);
```

}

What happens here is that two properties are created; expression and direction.

By using the sortDirection object to set the sorting (descending or ascending) and the string ''expression'' that can be used to target certain colums to sort and using those as parameters for the .Sort method, your desired effect can be used.

**Edit**

Forgot to add the source of the code.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sort(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i need the sorting event to fire when the user clicks its column

Comment: You can use this code inside the event handler and get the column properties to fill "expression" with the right value, so the Sort method can do it for you. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting(v=vs.110).aspx